# postgresql No space left on device

Tags: postgresql

Postgres is reporting that it is out of disk space while performing a rather large aggregation query:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not write block 31840050 of temporary file: No space left on device
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1592)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1327)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:192)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:451)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:350)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:189)
    ... 8 more
```

However the disk has quite a lot of space:

```
Filesystem            Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             386G  123G  243G  34% /
udev                  5.9G  172K  5.9G   1% /dev
none                  5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev/shm
none                  5.9G  628K  5.9G   1% /var/run
none                  5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /var/lock
none                  5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /lib/init/rw
```

The query is doing the following:

```
INSERT INTO summary_table SELECT t.a, t.b, SUM(t.c) AS c, COUNT(t.*) AS count,
    t.d, t.e, DATE_TRUNC('month', t.start) AS month, tt.type AS type, FALSE, tt.duration
FROM detail_table_1 t, detail_table_2 tt
WHERE t.trid=tt.id  AND tt.type='a'
    AND DATE_PART('hour', t.start AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney' AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')>=23
        OR DATE_PART('hour', t.start AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney' AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')<13
GROUP BY month, type, t.a, t.b, t.d, t.e, FALSE, tt.duration
```

any tips?

Comment: Sure, now that the query's stopped and the temporary files it was using are gone, the drive isn't as full anymore.  What did `df` look like while the query was in progress?

Comment: am re-running and watching now. will take 2+ hrs to get to the fail point i suspect.

Comment: @DerfK,if it is that the query was paging that much data, would breaking the insert into multiple inserts by adding date range help? - currently it does 6 years at once, maybe do a year at a time?

Comment: @pstanton That should help.

Comment: @DerfK How would a query generate more than 5.9 GB of temp files? That's a *ton* of temp files

Comment: @TheLQ Assuming that his actual database takes up most of that 123GB, all he needs to do is join two tables that are 60 GB each, without the RAM to hold it all in.  At 31840050 (8KiB) blocks, his query is certainly *huge*.

Comment: the database does take up most of the 123GB, however these 2 tables only take up 1296 MB and 968 kB respectively.

Comment: the db takes up 189 GB .. but i just dropped some tables and got it back down to 120 ish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for all the tips, a learn a few things from this mistake but ultimately my query was wrong!!

i missed parenthesis around an or clause!

of course i feel like an idiot.

Comment: Instead of letting people know the resolution of your issue here, just edit your original question.

Comment: @sciurus i have to close it off somehow .. otherwise it will never be correctly answered.

Comment: Any idea why it was generating that out of space error?

Comment: Same error here, same cause : wrong query.  I was trying to `CREATE TABLE AS` but the `SELECT FROM JOIN` clause was probably selecting N×N rows or more.  The issue was straightforward after printing the output of the `SELECT FROM JOIN` with a `LIMIT 10` clause.  So the query is probably the first thing to check when encountering this error.

Answer (score 6):

Also check the output of "df -i", which reports the number of inodes in use. Running out of inodes will also tend to generate "no free space" type errors, but you still have plenty of free space.

Comment: I'm going to admit I missed the point in the the OP's error output where it says "could not write block 31840050". As DerfK pointed out, postgres uses 8KiB blocks by default, so that query really is trying to write out 31840050 * 8KiB / (1024*1024) = 242.92 GiB. It might still be inode related, but that figure is close enough to the free space on / that it smells like a more likely culprit